# How can I make symlinks imperceptable to Firefox?

Tags: symlink, firefox

I'm running Ubuntu 22, and Firefox is installed via snap.  It stores profiles and cache in /home/username/snap/firefox/common.  I want to preserve profiles across system disk restores, and so I like to keep them on a secondary drive, symlinked back to their proper place on the system disk.  I've been doing this with Chromium for years, but now I'm switching to firefox.  When I symlink like so:

```
ln -s /second-disk/firefox-common /home/username/snap/firefox/common
```

After moving the contents to the second disk, and deleting the original directory, firefox won't launch because the profile is missing and it can't write another one.  Permissions are set properly.  Looking around online I see this same issue from other people with no solution.  Apparently firefox is mistrustful of symlinks in it's profile path for security reasons.

Is there some way to make the link imperceptible to Firefox?

Comment: Could apparmor be preventing firefox from using dirs and files under `/second-disk`?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it certainly has a problem no matter where the target of the link is.  It seems it's problem is just the use of links.

Comment: It's not Firefox, it's the snap packaging that keeps Firefox from accessing the outside location. One way out is to stick with the .deb version of Firefox. The Ubuntu Mozillateam offers this through https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa